How to achieve non-whitespace margins in printed version of webpage
Consider the following example:


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    font-size: 10pt;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.filler 
{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%
}

.left-column {
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 200%;
    width: 32%;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.right-column {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 32%);
    height: 200%;
}

@page {
    margin: 0
}
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="all" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="left-column">
            <div class="filler"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-column">
            <div class="filler"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



I would like the printed version of this webpage to extend to two pages. However, the padding only gets applied to the beginning of the first page and the end of the last page:

I understand why this happens, but I don't understand how to remediate it, since doing the following:
@page {
    margin: 1
}

Will add whitespace to the tops and bottoms of my pages, when in fact I want to preserve the colors of the left and right bands in my document, corresponding to the div elements with classes left-column and right-column.
Is it possible to achieve the result I want to the printed version of my webpage?

I may have misunderstood the problem, but are you certain your printer is set to do borderless printing? [or is it even able to do that?]

I'm not printing this to a physical printer. Just PDF. I assume if the PDF is borderless then any modern printer should be able to print that to physical paper?

I'm  not an expert on printers, but do know many can't do borderless, and the one I have can only do it if set as such, and then only from one of its trays and on heavy paper. Hope someone knows how PDF files and borders can be affected.

Even the page-margin properties specified according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page have not yet been implemented by any user agent. And since you want margins on <div> elements rather than entire pages, your requirement sounds even more complex than that.

Margin is outside an element, but padding is inside - have you tried using that instead?

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

My real use case involves use of Puppeteer to print this 2-page document out to a PDF. It turns out that Puppeteer has PDF options in place which allow you to inject HTML into the header and footer of the resulting PDF file. See headerTemplate and footerTemplate in the API reference. Using these templates I was able to achieve the behavior I wanted.
